# Crash connected with large successBlocks in NSOperations (memory issue)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, core-graphics

I have a `UICollectionView`. Inside each cell when it is displayed, i'm trying to cache the image. Firstly i download it, then i save it on disc (later i read from disc but now this is commented out to simplify the case. To make sure it is not causing the problem I've tested with leaks/allocations instruments).

So In each cell i call a method with `successBlock`.

```
// inside collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:
[self imageForObject:myObject withCompletionBlock:myCompletitionBlock];
```

Then i'm creating `NSOperation` and adding it to the queue (with `maxConcurrentOperationCount == 5`)

```
NSOperation *operation = [self fetchImageWithProperties:propertiesHere 
                                        processingBlock:processingBlock 
                                                success:success 
                                                failure:failure];
[_myQueue addOperation:operation];
```

In method fetchImage I use `AFNetworking` (1.3.3, too much time now to change it to 2.2) method:

```
imageRequestOperationWithRequest:imageProcessingBlock:success:failure:
```

Where on `successBlock` I save image to the disc (method pasted below). Here the problem is generated. When i swipe the cells very fast, my memory can jump so high app can crash. Later it ofc is dropping. I can get rid of the problem via commenting out `CGImageDestination..` methods, but then whole cache idea is without sense as image is not saved.

```
CGImageDestinationRef idst = 
  CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)myUrl, 
                                  (__bridge CFStringRef)myImageType, 
                                  1, 
                                  (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options);
if (imageDest != NULL) {
     // if i comment out following 2 methods, memory do not increase
     CGImageDestinationAddImage(idst, 
                                myImageCgImageRef, 
                                (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)myOptions);
     CGImageDestinationFinalize(idst);
     CFRelease(idst);
}
```

I also have to add, that in method `collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` I'm canceling operation from the cell.

What can cause the problem with memory?

BTW: What may be surprising, `_myQueue.operations.count` sometimes is around 7.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method `CFRelease(idst)` outside of `if` condition. Because you've responsible for this release if it's created. This may lead to memory problem.

```
CGImageDestinationRef idst = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)myUrl, (__bridge CFStringRef)myImageType, 1, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options);
 if (imageDest != NULL) {
      // if i comment out following 2 methods, memory do not increase
      CGImageDestinationAddImage(idst, myImageCgImageRef, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)myOptions);
      CGImageDestinationFinalize(idst);
 }
CFRelease(idst);
```

Comment: I've changed it and tested in the instruments. The memory is still jumping to the same level.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that, when the app does not crash, memory goes down to normal levels after the spike, we can rule out memory leaks or abandoned memory as the root cause of the crash.

One important resource in such cases are memory warnings. You will surely get a series of them before the crash. You should try to free as many of the resources you have allocated in you memory warning handlers. To see where memory accumulates, try and take memory snapshots of your app when it is doing the image processing step (Instruments/Allocations tool/both living and dead objects).

Beside this, I would try a different approach to saving your image to file:

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
//-- alternatively:    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imgData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Just in case it is more memory efficient than `CGImageDestination`.

On a different note, you could also try and reboot your device and see what happens with fresh memory. iOS devices tend to get to a state where almost any task can cause a crash due to memory pressure.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion with rebooting device. It is happening on at least 6 devices, so it cannot be a reason. If by snapshot you mean `mark generation` I've tried it but response is unreadable for me. In `Generation1` growth is 10MB, in `Generation2` growth is 200KB while in allocation it changed around ~12MB meantime. Object names also doesn't help (`VM:CGRasterData`=3MB, `<non-object>`=2MB, `VM:CoreAnimation`=1MB).

Comment: what about `NSData writeToFile`? does it improve things? and what about if you try with maximum 3 outstanding operations? suggesting this just to pin down the issue… btw, are you seeing the memory warnings in the console log?

Comment: Yes, i can see memory warnings in the console log. I've tried with writeToFile, still can crash. I've even tried to decrease max operations to 1, but still had memory problems :/